How to disavow backlinks from the Bing group of websites?
I manage a website for a blues band. I recently posted some gigs on a local information site. Google webmaster tools correctly shows 3 backlinks from this site. Bing shows 434 backlinks from the same  page but with different query strings. The content of that same page varies because it contains many nonces to mask email addresses. As a result of this (I suspect) the Bing group of search engines no longer list my site. Google is fine. How can I disavow these links (Bing seem to have removed the facility to do it manually - they say their AI will do it - which it doesn't)? I have tried to contact Bing support and DuckDuckGo support but they don't reply.
